# Email Verfication - Site keep blank - PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am sending to me a email when a new User has sign-up to aprove it. Now I have this verify.php Code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "database", "pw", "databasename") or die(mysql_error()); // Connect to database server(localhost) with username and password.
mysql_select_db("databasename") or die(mysql_error()); // Select registration database.

if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])){
    // Verify data
    $email = mysql_escape_string($_GET['email']); // Set email variable
    $hash = mysql_escape_string($_GET['hash']); // Set hash variable

    $search = mysql_query("SELECT email, hash, active FROM users WHERE email='".$email."' AND hash='".$hash."' AND active='0'") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $match  = mysql_num_rows($search);

    if($match > 0){
        // We have a match, activate the account
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET active='1' WHERE email='".$email."' AND hash='".$hash."' AND active='0'") or die(mysql_error());
        echo '<div class="statusmsg">Your account has been activated, you can now login</div>';
    }else{
        // No match -> invalid url or account has already been activated.
        echo '<div class="statusmsg">The url is either invalid or you already have activated your account.</div>';
    }

}else{
    // Invalid approach
    echo '<div class="statusmsg">Invalid approach, please use the link that has been send to your email.</div>';
}
?>
```

I get everything.. the mail with correct link:

```
http://www.yourwebsite.com/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.'
```

But once I click the link it just stays in blank Website.. No error but no Change to... :(... Pretty sure there is small error I cant find..

Comment: no errors; well I don't see error reporting syntax anywhere

Comment: Same.. But once I click the link the site stays just in blank.. and no changes done in the database :)

Comment: Site blank, suggests to me a 500 and php death. Probably from the use of `mysql_*` functions...

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by you get mail with link `http://www.yourwebsite.com/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.'` ... what is that. Where is that. I don't see that link being made in your code. And if thats the link you get, then thats not a correct link at all.

Comment: Do you think it is secure to send _via Email, a very insecure mechanism_ the users hashed password??? I assume that the hashed password

Comment: @RiggsFolly I dont know what he is trying to do, but that does look horribly scary.

Comment: Ist just to active the user.. The Mail I get Comes from the sign-up from:

`Please click this link to activate your account:
http://www.website.com/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.'`

On the Mail it Looks right.. the Link I send its just source Code.

Comment: If `$hash` is a temporary code generated and stored on the user row, then you dont need anything else in the querystring. That code should uniquely identify the user

Comment: @RiggsFolly For each user-Signup there is hashcode generated. And when I recive the mail the link is correct.. it Shows the hashcode that is in the DB to.. but still blank site only and no updates

Comment: Is it possible that the `real_escape_string()` is changing something in the email or hash string?

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I wonder what version PHP he is using.... hmm. Jerome? Also add `ini_set('display_errors', true);  error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script.

Comment: @RiggsFolly , I just Change all to mysqli , now at least getting the The url is either invalid or you already have activated your account.. I checked but email and hascode is exactly the same on the DB when I see the Link that I get to confirm.

Comment: Please don't edit the title with "Solved" or including the solution in the question. I rolled the question back to a previous revision. Either delete the question or post your own answer below. Then, mark it as solved once it lets you. By doing that, it automatically marks your question as being solved. Questions and answers are two different animals.

Comment: Maybe a '@' disables error reporting...

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);
$link = $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "database", "pw!", "database");


// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])){
    // Verify data
    $email = mysqli_escape_string($link, $_GET['email']); // Set email variable
    $hash = mysqli_escape_string($link, $_GET['hash']); // Set hash variable
    $passwort = mysqli_escape_string($link, $_GET['passwort']); // Set hash variable

    $passwort_hash = password_hash($passwort, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $search = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT email, hash, active, passwort FROM users WHERE email='".$email."' AND hash='".$hash."' AND active='0'") or die(mysqli_error()); 
    $match  = mysqli_num_rows($search);

    if($match > 0){
        // We have a match, activate the account
        mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE users SET active='1' WHERE email='".$email."' AND hash='".$hash."' AND active='0'") or die(mysqli_error()); 
        echo '<div class="statusmsg">Your account has been activated, you can now login</div>';

    }else{
        // No match -> invalid url or account has already been activated.
        echo '<div class="statusmsg">The url is either invalid or you already have activated your account.</div>';
    }

}else{
    // Invalid approach
    echo '<div class="statusmsg">Invalid approach, please use the link that has been send to your email.</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this line:

> > if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])){

You have used "AND" here. It should be:

> if((isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email'])) && (isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash']))){

---

I have checked your script, It is working with some modifications. Possible error according to me is status datatype. it should be 'int' Please check below.:

```
if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])){
    // Verify data
    $email = mysql_escape_string($_GET['email']); // Set email variable
    $hash = mysql_escape_string($_GET['hash']); // Set hash variable

    $search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test_users WHERE u_email='".$email."' AND u_hash='".$hash."' ") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $match  = mysql_num_rows($search);

    if($match > 0){
        // We have a match, activate the account
        mysql_query("UPDATE test_users SET u_status='1' WHERE u_email='".$email."' AND u_hash='".$hash."'") or die(mysql_error());
        echo '<div class="statusmsg">Your account has been activated, you can now login</div>';
    }else{
        // No match -> invalid url or account has already been activated.
        echo '<div class="statusmsg">The url is either invalid or you already have activated your account.</div>';
    }

}else{
    // Invalid approach
    echo '<div class="statusmsg">Invalid approach, please use the link that has been send to your email.</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: AND whats the problem with that? What you presented is no different. Other than the order of comparrison, but given everything is an AND, then it does not matter.

Comment: _Small Note_ `AND` == `&&`

Comment: It would be better written as just `!empty($_GET['email']) and !empty($_GET['hash'])` ;)

Comment: Guys sorry I gave wrong answer, but please don't give me down votes anymore.

Comment: Hi.. What Modification you did? I just see other Name from Database then mine.. And what you mean with it should be "int" "active" is bei Default 0 int

Comment: you are using active key as a string. Make sure it is same as in database.

Comment: It is exactly like this in DB

Comment: Why on earth rename his database fields as a solution? Nothing you changed would make a difference here. :(

Comment: Can you just echo your $search query and execute the output in phpmyadmin or cli

Answer (score -2):

It's a bad idea to use die(), if this happens the error is logged to the Apache error log and you are left with a blank screen.  You should consider moving away from using this way of interacting with mysql and consider using PDO (https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) with prepared statements.

To see what the actual error is follow your web server error log and see what is being logged.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what `die( _some_string_here_ )` does. It does not send that string to an apache error log. It displays it to the browser. If he used errorno, then it would exit with that code. (ps: I was not the downvoter)

Comment: Without die() it still leaves me on blank Screen :) ... Yeah I know.. but I startet like this now :(